# convert three columns into percentages for the row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, percentage

I don't know how to put this best in words, but below is my data and i'm trying to build a query that will output each column as a percent of the three items of cash, planpay, govt

column data:

[image: 1]

output to be like:

[image: 2]

I have tried this

```
select str_nbr ,(sum(cast(planpay as float) / (sum(cast (planpay as float) + sum (cast (cash as float) + sum (cast (govt as float))) 

from Insurance where str_nbr in ( '15308') group by str_nbr
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: select 
 str_nbr
,(sum(cast(planpay as float) / (sum(cast (planpay as float) + sum (cast (cash as float) + sum (cast (govt as float))) 

 from Insurance
 where  str_nbr in ( '15308')
 group by str_nbr

Comment: And what was wrong with that? aside from having too much repetition and casts with unclear purpose (since you didn't show the types of the input columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use division.  If you don't want to repeat the calculation, use `apply`:

```
select t.str_nbr,
       t.cash * 100.0 / v.total as cash_pct,
       t.planpay * 100.0 / v.total as planpay_pct,
       t.govt * 100.0 / v.total as govt_pct
from t cross apply
     (values (cash + planpay + govt)) v(total)
```

Note that SQL Server does integer division.  So if the values are integers, then `1 / 2` is `0` rather than `0.5`.  The `* 100.0` fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same logic as in Excel, but in T-SQL. Avoid repetition with a CTE

```sql
with cte as (
  select
    str_nbr,
    CASH,
    PLANPAY,
    GOVT,
    CASH + PLANPAY + GOVT as total
  from Insurance
)
select
  str_nbr as store,
  100.0 * CASH    / total as cash,
  100.0 * PLANPAY / total as planpay,
  100.0 * GOVT    / total as govt
from cte;
```

Comment: @JasonM.Kluczyk edited to fix that by coercing to floating point first.

Comment: that also worked now, thank you for showing me that too